# JSPlumb query table connect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsplumb

I would like to connect two draggable divs with bootstrap table rows using jsPlumb. However source and target defined here,

```
jsPlumb.connect({source:"window2", target:"window1" });
jsPlumb.connect({source:"window1", target:"window3"});
```

Here is the fiddle of what I what I am trying.  https://codepen.io/pvnkk/pen/BGVEvw?editors=1010

Lines are not able to connect from one table row to another table row.
Using: `BS-4`, `Jquery-UI`

Answer (score 0):

JSPlumb container needs to be `position: relative` but the actual draggable element must be `position: absolute`.

You have it as `position: relative`.

Also, your JSPlumb js script is about 5 years old. Get the latest one [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jsPlumb).